# I don't know why Nginx server is not working

Tags: django, linux, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

Hi there i'm trying to put in production some django app using nginx + gunicorn + supervisor.

Following [this guide](https://rukbottoland.com/blog/django-gunicorn-nginx-supervisor/) i was able to reproduce all steps with success but for some reason i can't make it work. I believe that the problem is with the nginx part of the project since I'm not able to even serve a static file for testing. It's my first time using all these tools.

Config files are as follows:

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 1;

user nobody nogroup;
# 'user nobody nobody;' for systems with 'nobody' as a group instead
error_log  /home/seba94/log/nginx/nginx.error.log warn;
#pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024; # increase if you have lots of clients
  accept_mutex off; # set to 'on' if nginx worker_processes > 1
  # 'use epoll;' to enable for Linux 2.6+
  # 'use kqueue;' to enable for FreeBSD, OSX
}

http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  # fallback in case we can't determine a type
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /home/seba94/log/nginx/nginx.access.log combined;
  sendfile on;

  upstream app_server {
    # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
    # to return a good HTTP response

    # for UNIX domain socket setups
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=10s;

    # for a TCP configuration
    #server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
  }


  server {
    # if no Host match, close the connection to prevent host spoofing
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 444;
  }

  server {
    # use 'listen 80 deferred;' for Linux
    # use 'listen 80 accept_filter=httpready;' for FreeBSD
listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    # set the correct host(s) for your site
    server_name reg.rocstar.tv;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # path for static files
    root /home/seba94/static;

    location /register/ {
      # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
      try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }


    location /media/  {
      #path for Django media files
      alias /home/seba94/register-page/register_page/media;
    }

    location /static/ {
      #path for Django static files
      alias /home/seba94/register-page/register_page/static;
    }

    location /todd-logo.png {
      alias /home/seba94/static/todd-logo.png;
    }


    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
      # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
      root /home/seba94/static;
    }
  }
```

supervisord.conf:

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/home/seba94/log/supervisord/supervisord.log

[inet_http_server]
port=127.0.0.1:9001

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory=supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[program:register-page-django]
command=/home/seba94/.local/share/virtualenvs/register-page-jYLn8mRO/bin/gunicorn register_page.wsgi -c /home/seba94/conf/gunicorn.conf.py
directory=/home/seba94/register-page/register_page
user=seba94
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/home/seba94/log/supervisord/register_page.log
stderr_logfile=/home/seba94/log/supervisord/register_page.err.log

[supervisorctl]
```

gunicorn.conf.py:

```
import multiprocessing

#Server socket config
bind = "unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock"
backlog = 2048

#Workers config. Eventlet is an asynchronus worker
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
worker_class = "eventlet"
worker_connections = 1000


#access-logfile = "/home/seba94/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.log"
#error-logfile = "/home/seba94/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.error.log"


name = "register-page-gunicorn"


#Server mechanics
#daemon = True
```

I'm able to run successfully all processes with no errors from the cmd using the following commands:

- `sudo service nginx start`
- `sudo supervisord -c /home/seba94/conf/supervisord.conf`
- `sudo supervisorctrl start register-page-django`

Nginx status is the following:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-10-23 20:38:58 UTC; 31min ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 5552 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5599 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5594 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5601 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1108)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─5601 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           └─5760 nginx: worker process

oct 23 20:38:58 register-page-server systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
oct 23 20:38:58 register-page-server systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Honestly i can't find any errors not even in the log files so i don't know why i can't even see my static todd-logo.png file. Neither can i see the Django app running. Any help is more than welcomed

**Edit:**

Seems that all config files and commands in this issue are fine, the problem appeared to be a firewall configuration from a previous project. This could be an example of usage of these tools currently working

Comment: What error are you seeing other than it is not working

Comment: Make sure you are accessing the server using this url `http://reg.rocstar.tv`

Comment: I tried both using chrome and curl and no response at all. Changed my hosts file on my host windows machine to pair the server's ip to the domain and still nothing. @ShawnC I can't see no errors in any log file. Also no access on the access file

Comment: It seems that there was a problem with the firewall configuration that somehow was blocking my access from outside the server. Simply deactivated the firewall and i was able to access static content

Answer (score 0):

Please share the output of curl -v http://domain-name in the question as well.

Comment: forgot to comment and close the question, i had a firewall configuration from the begining preventing my project from working. Seems that all config files were just fine, also the execution of the different commands